# Multiple ResultSet in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to develop a site and I am facing a difficulty with fetching multiple result sets in a JSP.

```
    String query="select * from user";
    ResultSet rs=Dbmanager.fetchQuery(query);
```

This is the query I am firing. I have declared a method in a separate Dbmanager class;

```
public static ResultSet fetchQuery(String query)
{
    try
    {
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        return rs;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in DBManager..for fetchQuery.."+e.getMessage());
        return null;    
    }
}
```

What I want is to fetch data from user and cart table in my database. I have tried **UNION ALL** also. but it is giving me all the columns which I dont want. 
      I have tried to create 2 methods in Dbmanager as shown above and I am getting an error;
**Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed**
  Please help!

Comment: Would you like to edit your code properly?

Comment: I am sorry sir, I dont understand what you mean? If you can edit it for me then that would be swell!

Comment: Hello friend , I understand that you need . so you can see with that query bring more than one row from the database and you want to display them on a table in JSP ? or you need?

Comment: Hello Santiago! Thanks for replying.. What I want is to fetch 2 different queries from 2 tables. I want user_id from user and cart_id,Total_cost from cart table. I am designing a payment gateway.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question exactly?  Are you simply requesting code which joins your tables and selects the desired columns?

Comment: I want to fetch User_id from user table and Cart_id from cart table. When I executed the code I got an error: operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. What I want to know is that do I need to declare one more REsultset in Dbmanager file? because I tried that and I am getting the same error. I have written the code in scriplet tag in Payment.jsp

Comment: If you want data from diff tables, you should join tables nd fetch the data rather than executing two different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query to use JOIN. Here is a simple tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Also, if you don't want to retrieve all columns then don't use asterisk (*).